# icefaces spinner listener?

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I am using an enterprise component from icefaces: [numberSpinner](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/vEE_1_8_2_GA_P02/ee-composite-comps/tld/ice-cc/numberSpinner.html)

I know how to initialize it from the bean, for instance:

```
processorAlSpinner =  new NumberSpinner(1,1,100,null)
```

where the constructor is defined in their source code like:

```
public NumberSpinner(int number, java.lang.Integer min, java.lang.Integer max, com.icesoft.faces.facelets.component.spinner.INumberSpinnerListener spinnerListener);
```

What I do not know is how to specify a listener for it? (you noticed that I put null)

Their source code says:

> Specify an instance of INumberSpinnerListener in the constructor if
>   you would like to receive value change events

but how? I tried it like:

```
public INumberSpinnerListener testSpinnerListener() {
    logger.info("Listener called!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    return null;
}

processorAlSpinner =  new NumberSpinner(1,1,100,testSpinnerListener)
```

but the listener is not called when I change the spinner's value from UI so I think I am wrong...

Can you please give a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INumberSpinnerListener is an interface (I am assuming by the name), you thus need to create a class that implements that interface, e.g.:

```
class MyListener implements INumberSpinnerListener {
    // ... implementations of all the methods in the listener
}
```

Then you provide an instance of it in the call, e.g.:

```
processorAlSpinner =  new NumberSpinner(1,1,100, new MyListener());
```

If the interface is simple, you can also define an anonymous class directly, something like:

```
processorAlSpinner =  new NumberSpinner(1,1,100, new INumberSpinnerListener() {
    // ... implementations of all the methods in the listener
});
```